# How reliable is Herodotus' report on Babylonian sacred harlotry?

Tags: sources, bible, ancient-babylon, prostitution

I'm looking for confirmation regarding Herodotus' report on sacred harlotry in Babylon:

> The foulest Babylonian custom is that which compels every woman of the
> land to sit in the temple of Aphrodite and have intercourse with some
> stranger once in her life. Many women who are rich and proud and
> disdain to mingle with the rest, drive to the temple in covered
> carriages drawn by teams, and stand there with a great retinue of
> attendants. [Herodotus Book 1 Ch.
> 199](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D199%3Asection%3D1)

Sacred harlotry is also mentioned in the [Epic of Gilgamesh](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Gilgamesh,_Epic_of) where it seems clear this was a real, perhaps honored, practice but not that it was a requirement for all women. It also figures into the biblical narratives where both male (2 Kings 23:6-8) and female (Deuteronomy 23:17) sacred harlots are associated with Canaanite religion and even with the Temple in Jerusalem. It may also figure into the story of Judah and Tamar (Gen. 28) who disguised herself as a (sacred?) harlot to perpetuate Judah's lineage.  What I'm hoping to get from this question is confirmation from sources other than Herodotus that sacred harlotry was a *requirement* in Babylon and elsewhere, and if so, where/when.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_prostitution

Comment: @TomasBy thank you. The article is a good summary but doesn't provide a specific source other than Herodotus that speaks of the tradition as a requirement.

Comment: Basically, you have two camps: one says it never existed, and one says there is limited evidence for it. There is nothing exactly corroborating Herodotus.